# Is it possible to set a url to ":name" instead of "models/:id"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I have a model "User", which has a `:name` attribute. Right now, the User "show" action is defined by the following route:

```
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

This means that the "show" view for a User with `id: 4` and `name: Joe` would be under `localhost:3000/users/4`.

Is there a way I could get Joe's "show" url to be `localhost:3000/joe`, and do the same for every user? Every `:name` is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, do you mean this:

```
get '/:name', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

That should capture the `:name` attribute from the URL at the root level, but still go to the same controller.

Here's a link to the Rails Routing guide that I believe covers this (albeit not in too much detail): [Rails Routing: dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments)

Then to extract the `:name` attribute instead of the `:id` attribute change the code in the controller from `User.find(params[:id])` to `User.find_by(name: params[:name])`

[Rails Models - find_by method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-by)

Comment: That's the general idea I'm going for, but when I add that code and go to the url (in Joe's case `localhost:3000/joe`), I get a "Couldn't find User without an ID" error.

Comment: Hmm, now it's giving me "Couldn't find User with id=joe". I don't know why it's still looking for an id.

Comment: Ah. That's how the find method works. We need the 'find_by' method now. I'll update the answer to reflect that